# How do I fix 'No native build was found for runtime=electron abi=73 platform=win32glibc arch=x64'?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, ts-loader

## The error

I'm using webpack version `4.41.1`, webpack-dev-server version `3.8.2` and electron version `6.0.12`, and once my build is complete I use this code to open the electron app

```
if (dev) {
  mainConfig.plugins.push({
    apply: compiler => {
      compiler.hooks.afterEmit.tap('AfterEmitPlugin', () => {
        if (electronProcess) {
          electronProcess.kill();
        }

        electronProcess = spawn('npm', ['start'], {
          shell: true,
          env: process.env,
          stdio: 'inherit',
        })
          .on('close', code => process.exit(code))
          .on('error', spawnError => console.error(spawnError));
      });
    },
  });
}
```

## How the error happens

Then, it runs `npm start`, and it starts electron, if you check the console the app fails to load with this error:

[image: the error]
https://hastebin.com/moheyikofa.

## What I've tried

I've already tried reporting this to the Electron devs, however they told me this is a libgc error and to tell the authors of libgc, however the libgc repository is read-only; so I'm unable to open an issue about it.

## My webpack code

I have my webpack config in multiple files, to keep each category organized.

Base Webpack Config (everything built on top of this): https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dot-browser/desktop-webpack-bug/master/webpack.config.base.js

Electron Main Webpack Config: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dot-browser/desktop-webpack-bug/master/webpack.config.js

Electron Renderer Webpack Config: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dot-browser/desktop-webpack-bug/master/webpack.config.renderer.js

Browser Webpack Config (I load these pages into the BrowserView of my electron app, so they must be browser, and not electron-renderer): https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dot-browser/desktop-webpack-bug/master/webpack.config.web.js

I expect the app to load, because my friend uses almost the same config, and it loads perfectly fine.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem?

Comment: No, but I found removing `leveldown` in my code to fix the issue.